# Sign in with Apple - is the whole Access Token Revoke Dance fully required?

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth-2.0, apple-sign-in

My app recently got a review remark from Apple that I must have Account deletion mechanism in my app (which uses Sign in with Apple). It also says I should **revoke tokens** issued by Apple.

In response, I have handled it as part of my UI as well as back end. I delete user's sandbox data, keychain data as well as the user record on the server.

As for the token, I do not use standard access/revoke token advised by Apple.

Here is what I do:

1 - Sign in with Apple on the device
2 - Get ID token
3 - Send it to my server
4 - My Server will create a JWT based on PEM file I got from Apple
5 - Send that JWT to iOS client
6 - Client will use it until it expires.
7 - When it expire, I again force the user to do SIWA.

This way, I know the user is a valid Apple user (I don't have Android plans). I kind of lived with this because I thought this was Apple's way of minimizing our hassle to do less server dance.

I also developed the SIWA part before 2022 when this rule came into effect, hence also chose SIWA for its simplicity.

Well, not quite.

Now that I see it, all I am doing is generating a client secret, which is 1-step away Access token. So how do I even go about revoking it?

- At present, my attempts to obtain an [Apple access token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accountorganizationaldatasharing/generate-and-validate-tokens) from SIWA returned authorization code + my JWT (client secret) meets with `invalid_client` error code.
- There is [plenty of Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accountorganizationaldatasharing/creating-a-client-secret), but strands of information are here and there. All one can do is trial and error. Such a complex topic requires more elaborate explanation. Instead of providing samples, Apple points to external sites (Jwt.io) instead of trying to be a source of truth.
- Googling does not get me any sample implementation, or even standard steps I should follow if I don't have complex requirements. Do I have to rely on [3rd party like Firebase whose tutorials](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/ios/how-to-figure-out-the-sign-in-with-apple-token-revocation-requirements-after-june-30th/14966) are readily available?

I get that security is a delicate topic. But to me, after JWT step, it's between my server and iOS users, I truly don't see the point of doing so many hops for authentication.

I naively chose SIWA to minimize server management, but it seems I am falling on my face. If I was doing this with email, I would only be creating JWT and it would probably be enough, which I am doing anyway now.

What am I missing here?

(**A humble request**: I would highly appreciate experiences of developers who have implemented this, not just a recap of Apple's rules. With little clarity on the details, coding it in 48 hours is no big deal for me. OTOH, if there is a source that cites I can bypass token revoke flow, please share as well.)

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear @matt. Is there an implementation guideline how one can test generate Access token payload, and revoke it? I am following all the Apple docs guidelines but not getting success.

Comment: Also is it really mandatory I use Apple's access token for SIWA, instead of my JWT signed with Apple's pem file?

Comment: I don't know what's mandatory. We basically just do what's described in Apple's "Implementing User Authentication with Sign in with Apple".